# Finding unique objects inside parent array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I have an array of objects like below:

```
const myArray = [
    {
      main_query: "query-1",
      conditions: [
        {
          field: "branch_primary",
          query: "1"
        },
        {
          field: "web_domain",
          query: "google.de"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      main_query: "query-1",
      conditions: [
        {
          field: "branch_primary",
          query: "2"
        },
        {
          field: "web_domain",
          query: "google.de"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      main_query: "query-1",
      conditions: [
        {
          field: "branch_primary",
          query: "3"
        },
        {
          field: "web_domain",
          query: "google.de"
        }
      ]
    }
];
```

Please notice that I have nested array of objects with the **key: conditions** inside my each parent object. All three main parent objects have the **keys: main_query and conditions**.

main_query has a value of string and they are the same for all three of the main objects.

conditions are array of objects again with the **keys: field and query**

All three main objects have same key value pairs/look same except **query key value** for **field:"primary_branch"** which is 1, 2, 3 respectively.

I am using below code to find out the unique array of objects.

```
const keys = ["main_query", "conditions"];
const filtered = myArray.filter(
  ((s) => (o) =>
    ((k) => !s.has(k) && s.add(k))(keys.map((i) => o[i]).join("|")))(
    new Set()
  )
);
const result = filtered.map((o) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k) => [k, o[k]])));

console.log(result);
```

Unfortunately the result I am getting is below:

```
{
  main_query: "query-1",
  conditions: [{
      field: "branch_primary",
      query: "1"
    },
    {
      field: "web_domain",
      query: "google.de"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am expecting all three of the objects to be displayed in the console because the field "primary_branch" has different query values.

Expected Output should be:

```
{
  main_query: "query-1",
  conditions: [{
      field: "branch_primary",
      query: "1"
    },
    {
      field: "web_domain",
      query: "google.de"
    }
  ]
}, {
  main_query: "query-1",
  conditions: [{
      field: "branch_primary",
      query: "2"
    },
    {
      field: "web_domain",
      query: "google.de"
    }
  ]
}, {
  main_query: "query-1",
  conditions: [{
      field: "branch_primary",
      query: "3"
    },
    {
      field: "web_domain",
      query: "google.de"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Here my link to the codepen regarding this code.](https://codepen.io/audhit/pen/OJNgGaO)

Comment: For anyone else confused by this code, it uses a concept called [currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `JSON.stringify` to create an identifier for your objects, taking into account that we should not rely on property order in objects, and that the order of objects inside `conditions` is not relevant, so I suggest to sort the conditions by field, and encode everything as array:

```
const stringify = ({main_query, condtions}) =>
    JSON.stringify([
        main_query, 
        ...condtions.map(({field, query}) => [field, query])
                    .sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
    ]);

let result = Array.from(new Map(myArray.map(query => [stringify(query), query])).values());
```

Comment: wow, it is looking like an awesome solution @trincot....let me give it a shot and try to understand your code..i will get back to you asap after testing it..thanks a lot

Comment: so, it is working like a charm..thanks a lot, i am accepting your answer..cheers

Answer (score 0):

A lot more complicated then the other answer, but here it is my *working* solution to it:

```
function uniqueItems(arr) {
    var uniqueArr = [], uniqueArrStrings = [];
    arr.forEach(el => {
        if(!uniqueArrStrings.includes(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(el).toString()).toString())) {
            uniqueArrStrings.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(el).toString()).toString());
            uniqueArr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(el).toString()));
        };
    });
    return uniqueArr;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This will give a unique array of objects

```
for(var myObj of myArray) {
    var set = new Set();
    for(var i = 0; i < myObj.conditions.length; i++) {
        var condition = myObj.conditions[i];
        var strCond = JSON.stringify(condition);
        if(set.has(strCond)) {
            myObj.conditions.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        set.add(strCond);
    }
}
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: try your code on `const myArray = [{conditions:[1]},{conditions:[1]}]`, it prints the original array...

Comment: @arVi, i tested it, sorry it is not working unfortunately..you can try my codepen and test yourself..sorry

Answer (score -2):

Make a function that takes as an input the array with objects, and gives as an output another array, but only with unique objects inside ( works with any type of value or object ).

```
function uniqueItems(arr) {
    let uniqueArr = [];
    arr.forEach(el => {
        if (!uniqueArr.includes(el)) {
            uniqueArr.push(el);
        };
    });
    return uniqueArr;
};
```

Comment: The OP is about array of object. Try your code on `uniqueItems([{a:1},{a:1}])`. Both objects are "unique" in the way that they are simply different objects, but probably not what the OP requires.. More importantly, your answer does not provide information how to solve the OP's problem

Comment: sorry dude, it is a bit more complicated than you are thinking @smunteanu

Comment: I would have downgraded my own answer if I could *facepalm*

Comment: @smunteanu just learn from it, it very good outcome :-)